# Why are you able to redirect to a named route in Laminas, and insert a controller and an action?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, laminas

In Laminas (Ex-Zend): Why are you able to redirect to a named and specified route (for example 'home') with the and give a controller and an action into the parameters, like this:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('home', ['controller'
 => 'NotHome', 'action' => 'displayAll])
```

Doesn't this the destroy the purpose of using a named route, if you just overwrite it with your own controller and action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't redirect you directly to this controller, but to URL generated using the given route and params. If route home doesn't have a placeholder for controller param, especially is Literal and not Segment type, the parameter will have no effect on redirection result.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it